# how to wait in each loop for every increment steps until inner process not successes?

Tags: asynchronous, meteor, underscore.js, each

I have list of data which is in array format for example:

```
var resultArray = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
```

I have used this array iteration in my code like this:

```
var updateArray = [];
_.each(resultArray, function (value, index) {
    //execute this function for file uploading.. 
    processMyFunction(value, function (error, success) {
        if(error) {
            //code to push it in my new array list
            updateArray.push({value:value,message:error});
        }
        else {
            //code to push it in my new array list
            updateArray.push({value:value,message:error});
        }
    });
    console.log(updateArray)
});
```

Here it does not gives me updated console. As uploading function takes time to do it's action and it come out from this `processMyFunction` function.
How should i make this _.each to wait until my function does not complete it's process?

Any suggestion on that?

Answer (score 0):

How about using async/await in combination with reduce?
With ES7 this should be possible.

e.g.

```
updateArray = await updateArray.reduce(async (acc, value) => {
    acc = await acc;

    await processMyFunction(value, function (error, success) {
        if(error) {
            //code to push it in my new array list
            acc.push({value:value,message:error});
        }
        else {
            //code to push it in my new array list
            acc.push({value:value,message:error});
        }
    });

    return acc;

}, []);

console.log(updateArray);
```

**UPDATE**
After I did some research on this, I also found [this](https://www.okgrow.com/posts/writing-asynchronous-code-in-meteor-and-javascript) interesting post.

Comment: @Remin i'm using old version on the update version of meteor V 1.3. Can you please suggest me code for this version. I do not want to upgrade version.

Comment: @Meteor: You have multiple approaches in the link I provided.

Comment: await doesn't work for me. Can you give other alternative to achieve this, link is not understandable for me?